# Conversion of kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCrBiPlanarVideoRange to kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, metal, accelerate

In an iOS app I am working on, the image is captured in `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange`(to be send over in network) but later in the app I want it converted to `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` (to be used for Deep Learning inference).
I am unable to perform this conversion properly. I found some help in the apple documentation @ [vImageConvert_420Yp8_Cb8_Cr8ToARGB8888(*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1533193-vimageconvert_420yp8_cb8_cr8toar); which is a function that

> Converts a YUV 420Yp8_Cb8_Cr8 format image to an ARGB8888 format image.

This seems like it would fit perfectly for my use case. But I am unable to figure out how to get the arguments `srcYp`, `srcCb` and `srcCr`. The function definition is:

```
func vImageConvert_420Yp8_Cb8_Cr8ToARGB8888(_ srcYp: UnsafePointer<vImage_Buffer>, 
                                      _ srcCb: UnsafePointer<vImage_Buffer>, 
                                      _ srcCr: UnsafePointer<vImage_Buffer>, 
                                      _ dest: UnsafePointer<vImage_Buffer>, 
                                      _ info: UnsafePointer<vImage_YpCbCrToARGB>, 
                                      _ permuteMap: UnsafePointer<UInt8>!, 
                                      _ alpha: UInt8, 
                                      _ flags: vImage_Flags) -> vImage_Error
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `vImageConvert_420Yp8_CbCr8ToARGB8888` since the chroma values are in one plane, not two.

I found [this example](https://gist.github.com/aabewhite/c584b8af1493a4fd3e995529e3029e5b) on how to convert the pixel buffer planes to `vImage_Buffers` and pass them to the function. Maybe it helps.